# affine transform (shear) calculate output shape

Tags: python, opencv, affinetransform

I want to apply an affine transformation (using scipy ndimage.affine_transform).
In particular I want to apply a shear in both dimensions so my transform matrix looks something like this:

```
        transform = np.array([[1, degree_v, 0],
                              [degree_h, 1, 0],
                              [0, 0, 1]])
```

the resulting image received by

`ndimage.affine_transform(img, transform)`

is cropped (which makes sense) and as I understand I have to give the correct `output_shape` and `offset` to keep the image uncropped.

How do I calculate these values?

Comment: That's a math question, isn't it? Or do you know how to calculate these values on paper and are asking how to pass them to `affine_transform`?

Comment: I don't know how to calculate them. I had an idea but it didn't work. So yeah I guess its primarily a math question.

Comment: Math and development are always close to each other. If you share your code and your example image (so your case is minimal and reproducible) and tell what is the expected result it may become a valid stackoverflow question!

Comment: define the corners of the input image, literally (0,0), (width,0) and so on. transform these points. now you know where the input image will be mapped to.